# C++: Why does only the key have to be const in a const std::pair?

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, constants, multimap

I am relatively new to C++, and have only just discovered how to use maps and pairs.

When looping over a map I created, which holds voltage keys and time values, I declare the loop variable a const pair& (a const reference).

Why is it that only the key in the template arguments has to be declared const (as follows)?

```
std::multimap<double, double> V_t;
// ... fill it up here
for (const std::pair<const double, double> &pair : V_t) {
            std::cout << pair.first << " volts at time: " << pair.second << std::endl;
        }
```

Why could I not write:

```
for (const std::pair<double, double> &pair : V_t) {
            std::cout << pair.first << " volts at time: " << pair.second << std::endl;
        }
```

? (I CAN write this, but my IDE does not like it)

Any clarification would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: C++ isn't smart enough to know that `const std::pair<double,double>` and `std::pair<const double, double>`  are compatible. When you have a reference to something, it has to be a reference to that exact type, or its base class, or a const/volatile version of it or its base class

Comment: You can avoid having to figure out the correct type by using `const auto &pair` instead.

Comment: @user253751 thank you!! It's nice to know I'm not going crazy :P

Comment: @user17732522 ah yes thanks that'll save me a lot of typing too :) !

Answer (score 2):

Every instantiation of a template is a completely new type. `std::pair<double, double>` and `std::pair<const double, double>` are completely different types. They have no relation whatsoever.

And a reference has to bind to an exact type, or a base class of it, or a non-const/non-volatile variation of it. You can't bind an `int&` to an `unsigned int` and you can't bind a `std::pair<double, double>&` to a `std::pair<const double,double>`. Not even if the reference is const.

Although it would make sense for `std::pair<const double, double>` - or `std::pair<const double, const double>` - to be compatible with `const std::pair<double, double> &`, C++ isn't smart enough to do that.

If you were on the C++ language committee and you wanted it to work, it's hard to imagine how you would make it work.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. This makes perfect sense actually.